# Click on a icon based on a different element

Tags: selenium-ide

```
<#a href="javascript:.ListSubfunds.edit_subfund('JSIT0', 'C123');"><#span class="icon icon-edit"><#/span><#/a>

<#a href="javascript:.ListSubfunds.edit_subfund('JSIT1', 'C345');"><#span class="icon icon-edit"><#/span><#/a>

<#a href="javascript:.ListSubfunds.edit_subfund('JSIT2', 'C659');"><#span class="icon icon-edit"><#/span><#/a>
```

I need to click the correct `<#span class="icon icon-edit"><#/span>` based on text "JSIT1" within the <#a> tag ("href"). I'm trying to do this using selenium IDE firefox.

I'm brand new to selenium and not sure if this will work. The reason for this task is: 
I am doing a manual job of updating data on a website so I'm trying to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an optimal way of selecting the element, but since you didn't provide any more of the HTML, the best I can do is the following XPath for you to try:

```
//a[contains(@href,'JSIT1')]
```